# After a windows update restart explorer.exe does not load

Tags: windows, boot, windows-10, windows-explorer, troubleshooting

My computer restarted on its own (before the restart everything was working fine for 2 years I have not done any significant software/setting changes the past month atleast and no hardware changes)

Now after logging into my windows account I have only a black screen with a mouse...

I open task manager and try to start explorer.exe (as an administrator or not) and it just **doesnt do anything** EVERYTHING else works though = I can start whatever I want from task manager like browsers other programs watch movies play games etc only explorer.exe doesnt work... I installed also a program that I downloaded successfully (tuneup utilities)

Its really furstrating everything working and all but explorer.exe not do anything for some reason..

I did check my computer with online antivirus scanners (like eset etc) I checked my computer with worm/rootkit removers and with my main antivirus (bitdefender 2016) I also checked my computer in rescue mode (were it restarts and loads a linux cernel and scans files -which I updated inside the linux distro- ) but I dont seem to have any viruses... also the cloud evaluation method of norton remover doesnt seem to show anything

Also "process explorer" + virustotal and "autoruns" + virustotal do not find anything in terms of malware...

I run a full checkdisk nothing

I run a DISM /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth

and then an sfc /scnnow

but nothing

I checked Device manager.... nothing....everything is as it supposed to be and no unknown decives etc also my Graphics card (GTX 650ti) in there and it was displayed as it should and no other graphics adapter was active

I updated my graphics driver

I cleaned the registry and everything else using ccleaner/bitdefender tools and tuneup utilities (which I also tried to use the windows fix tools like "fix task bar not appearing" etc) but nothing

I did restarted to troubleshoot mode and tried to troubleshoot windows boot but windows could not find any problem...

last peculiarity is that nothing else from the "startup list" seems to load except an irrelevant program I use -since years without a problem- and bitdefender  but even those programs dont load instantly as they used to they need a few minutes... (I had the PC open without restarting it for 4 hours now and nothing else loaded automatically )

But as I said everything else works (search,exploring files and open them or rename them or transfering them to any location, executables all work fine windows installer works fine sound, graphics etc all work fine)

what is the problem? :/ (I use windows 10 64 bit)

Comment: Does `explorer.exe` run if you boot into Safe Mode? Uninstall the most recently installed Windows updates that you believe have a role in this.

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention that... on safemode I cant log in because my profile doesnt load it loads the welcome screen the shutdown/restart buttons and the accessibility button but there is no tab to type my password and log in... lol I thought this would be a virus but as I state above nothing indicates to that.  I really cant understand why explorer.exe doesnt load while ALL the other executables load without any issues...